# How do I store data to tables in a 1-1 relationship (Single transaction)

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have this case where I need to add records to two tables that have a 1-1 relationship. (ex: table1 and table2) in a **single transaction**.

I first need to add the item to the `table1` and get the `id` of the item that just was added.
I now need to use `table1.id` to create the second item `table_one_id` that is a foreign key in `table2` with that id.

This is just to make sure that I don't have data in Table one if the second one failed!

`imagine table1 = users and table2 = cars`

I don't want to have `users.id` stored in the database if there is no `cars.userId`

Is there such a query, or what's the prefered method to do this?

Comment: 1:1 relation not exists. 1:(0 or 1) only.

Comment: @Akina of course it exists, https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56738/one-to-one-one-to-many-table-relationships-in-sql-server/

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Which environment?

Comment: @jarlh I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @jarlh but I just need the query in raw sql then I can modify it for postgreSQL

Comment: The <mysql> tag isn't related anyway.

Comment: *of course it exists* You just don't understand what the article describes.

Comment: 1:1 not exists! until DBMS allows insertion into 2 tables in one query ignoring intermediate reference violation. If not, none of tables allows new record insertion because no matched record in another, so you cannot insert data at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can even do that in a single *statement*

```
with new_parent as (
  insert into parent_table (<columns>)
  values (..)
  returning id; --<< this is the generated ID from parent_table
)
insert into child_table (parent_id, <other columns>)
select id, 42, 'some_value'
from new_parent;
```

Another option is to use `lastval()`:

```
insert into parent_table (<columns>)
values (..);
insert into child_table (parent_id, <other columns>)
values (lastval(), ...);
```